# How to specify local network for L2L VPN for a SonicWall w/ Standard OS.

Tags: vpn, sonicwall

I know you can do this on the enhanced OS but I can't find the option any where for the standard OS. It seems it just automatically uses the LAN subnet that is behind the SonicWall. I'm making a L2L VPN tunnel with a ASA 5510 and only have a few host on each side that need to use the tunnel.

I know ACLs is an option but I rather just classify the interesting traffic as the host that need access across the tunnel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out you can't do this. You have to upgrade to the Enhanced OS.